# jquery hide rows of a table based on cookie entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have an application where the user is able to select (checkbox) which rows should be shown on the page.

My table's rows has three id's (pending/approved/rejected)

The user is able to select  whether they would like to hide any of these three rows. Once the user selects this option, I save this in a cookie.

The next time the user logs on, this selection is pre-made based on the cookie. Everything is working fine, the only issue is that when the user logs on, there is a brief second when the page loads, then the javascript runs and hides the rows selected.

What I would like to have is the page render without the hidden rows if the cookie is set, essentially removing the unwanted effect of the table first rendering and then getting hidden.

Below is the code:

```
//reading the cookie value
var phide = $.cookie('pending_hide');
//If the cookie is set, then check the checkbox and hide the rows.
if (phide == 1) {
    $('.pending_form :checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    $('.pending').hide();
}    
//when user toggles checkbox, hide/show based on action and set cookie
$('.pending_form :checkbox').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            // the checkbox was checked 
            $('.pending').hide();
            $.cookie('pending_hide', 1);
        } else {
            // the checkbox was unchecked
            $('.pending').show();
            $.cookie('pending_hide', 0);
        }
});
```

Comment: How about mark the rows as hidden (`display:none`) by default, and then use the method you are already using to show the rows if you find relevant entry in the cookie? Just reverse the process!

Comment: Tried that, still saw the same behavior. Just opposite, a first empty table and then the JS kicks in and makes the rows visible. Unless I am missing something else.